# How to get max data via sap table connector look up in azure data factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, sap-dotnet-connector

I need to implement an incremental load for sap tables via the sap table connector in azure data factory within a copy activity.

Currently, I am trying to set the watermark of the sap table *(e.g. MAX(ERDAT))* through a lookup activity. Unfortunately, I cannot create a custom query,
because the sap table connector is very limited and only supports basic filtering options ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sap-table?tabs=data-factory#sap-table-as-source)).

Does someone know how to set a watermark via the sap table connector?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/load-sap-bw-data

This document providing the information regarding the watermark in SAP table connector. Check it out for the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is only a solution for the sap bw connector.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd prefer loading the delta e.g."ERDAT = today" to an OpenHub, then loading that regularly to Azure.

If that option does not work, using the link you provided, you can create a custom function module on SAP, and filter out records based on date.

Use this link for more info
https://www.cdata.com/kb/entries/sap-custom-read-table-function.rst